# Rubocop guard clause dilemma - unnecessary if else VS line too long guard clause

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have this piece of code where I have a raise statement with a guard clause:

```
def validate_index index
  # Change to SizeError
  raise ArgumentError, "Size of index (#{index.size}) does not matches"\
    "size of vector (#{size})" if size != index.size
end
```

On this, rubocop gives the offence:

```
Style/MultilineIfModifier: Favor a normal if-statement over a modifier clause in a multiline statement.
```

I modified my code to this to normal if else case as this:

```
def validate_index index
  # Change to SizeError
  if size != index.size
    raise ArgumentError, "Size of index (#{index.size}) does not matches"\
      "size of vector (#{size})"
  end
end
```

But now it gives this offence:

```
Style/GuardClause: Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression.
```

What to do in such case? Both are raising errors. Any other alternative?

Comment: You don't have to blindly follow everything rubocop says. You can disable GuardClause style check in `.rubocop.yml`

Comment: You can also disable individual items inline with # rubocop:disable and # rubocop:enable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rubocop wants you to write it like this:

```
def validate_index index
  # Change to SizeError
  return if size == index.size
  raise ArgumentError, "Size of index (#{index.size}) does not matches"\
  "size of vector (#{size})"
end
```

It is up to you if you want to go that route. Either way, Rubocop is also recommending:

```
def validate_index(index)
```

If you go your original route and ignore Rubocop, you should also really consider changing your `if !=` to an `unless`:

```
unless size == index.size
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

This will reduce the line length while raising the argument error

```
def validate_index index
  # Change to SizeError
  error_message = 
    "Size of index (#{index.size}) does not matches size of vector (#{size})"
  raise ArgumentError, error_message if size != index.size
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you think in concatenate with boolean expressions?, like:

```
def validate_index index
   # Change to SizeError
   size != index.size &&
     raise ArgumentError, "Size of index (#{index.size}) does not matches"\
     "size of vector (#{size})"
end
```